# About the HTTP communication required by the extension service worker

Tags: service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have heard that HTTPS communication is required for service workers used in extension manifest V3, but where exactly is HTTPS communication required?
・When I download extensions to my PC
・Sites that run extensions

Comment: There's no such requirement.

Comment: The following page says "Service workers only run over HTTPS", but is it different from the extension service worker?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: It doesn't apply to extensions, just ignore it.